# Query base type definiton as derived type using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have the following POCOs (using Code First and EF 6.0.0 alpha 3):

```
public class RevBase
{
    [Key]
    public int Id{ get; set; }
}

public class ItemBase
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public List<RevBase> Revs { get; set; }
}

public class RevDev : RevBase
{
    public string Content { get; set; }
}

public class ItemDev : ItemBase
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

and the following context

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    DbSet<ItemDev> Items { get; set; }
}
```

Now I would like to query `context.Items.Include(i => i.Revs)` but tell the EF somehow it should load the Revs as `RevDev` not `RevBase`.

Is that possible or do I need to load them as `RevBase` and make another query to get the according `RevDev` instances?

One other way I tried was creating a second relation from `RevDev` to `ItemDev`, but then EF also creates a second foreign key column in the DB which is not really necessary...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found out that Entity Framework does that by default. I had another error in my code why it did not work...

Comment: Hm, I probably misunderstood your question... (see my answer here) You actually want to include **all** `Revs`, but the ones that *are* `RevDev`s should be materialized as `RevDev`, not `RevBase`, right? Yes, that happens by default. (I thought you wanted to filter only the `Rev`s that are really `RevDev`s, and not only `RevBase`.)

Comment: Actually all my `RevBase` records which are assicioted to `ItemDev` are `RevDevs`, but through some screwup in my code the `RevDev` records in my DB where deleted and so they where loaded as `RevBase` and I did not get that until I debuged through the code and checked the DB records, sorry to cause you any inconvinienvce...

Answer (score 1):

> load the Revs as RevDev not RevBase

If a given `RevBase` is not a `RevDev` you can't load it *as* `RevDev`. (Not every animal is a dog. You cannot make every animal a dog, some are cats.)

Actually, what you need, I believe, is a *filter* by the type, which is generally a problem when using `Include` because it doesn't support any filtering at all. I see two options you have:

- Use explicit loading (which supports filtering):

  ```
  var items = context.Items.ToList();
  foreach (var item in items)
      context.Entry(item).Collection(i => i.Revs).Query()
          .Where(r => r is RevDev)
          .Load();
  ```

  These are 1 + N separate database queries.
- Use a projection:

  ```
  var items = context.Items
      .Select(i => new
      {
          Item = i,
          RevDevs = i.Revs.Where(r => r is RevDev)
      })
      .AsEnumerable()
      .Select(a => a.Item)
      .ToList();
  ```

  This is only one database query. Automatic relationship fixup should populate the `Item.Revs` collection with the loaded `RevDevs`.

Comment: Thanks for your input, as it contains some nice tips, but as stated in my own answer EF seems to already take care of that, as I debuged through my code and found out every `RevBase` which has an assicioted `RevDev` record is loaded as `RevDev`, meaning the `item.Revs` list contains `RevBase` and `RevDev` objects and I can then filter that list in code...